# An algorithm for grouping items according to "constrains" and "preferences"

Tags: algorithms

Before i explain exactly what i mean, let me just say that i never studied CS or low level programming, so i don't know much about the subject(I'm a self-taught JS programmer). To the point:

Imagine you have a group of workers, you need to construct a work-schedule for. Each worker has "constrains", meaning days/shifts(each day has three shifts, let's say) they **can't work on**, and "preferences", meaning their **more desired shifts**.

For example, John declares: "Can't work on Thursday at all; Can't work on Tuesday morning; Would like to have at least 4 shifts this week".

So imagine, that you have many shifts and many workers, and you need to construct a schedule that takes into consideration their requests as much as possible.

I'm sure this problem was already addressed. Can you maybe point me to the right direction, and direct me to some algorithm/methodology, from where i can start?

Comment: Sounds like some form of an assignment problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: You need to come up with a way of scoring a schedule. Once you have that, you can write a computer program, or use an existing program like MiniZinc, to look for a schedule that maximises this function subject to the constraints you mentioned. If your constraints are simple enough, this can be modelled and solved as an assignment problem, but if you have extra constraints like "Each worker must get some slot" then this won't work -- the problem is likely NP-hard in this case (meaning no efficient solution technique is known -- but small instances are still solvable via brute force).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "scoring a schedule"?

Comment: Preferences can be in conflict, so a program needs a way to decide which of several alternatives is considered "best." The usual way to do this is to come up with a way to assign a numeric score to *any* feasible (i.e., hard-constraint-meeting) solution: Then the program can always choose the highest-scoring one. Without this, you need an elaborate decision-making process -- and this can still result in impossible situations, like solution A is considered better than B which is considered better than C, which is considered better than A.

Comment: j_random_hacker: yes, i'm trying to implement a "weighted preference" matrix, by following this article: https://scheduling.philipithomas.com/scheduling.pdf